# How to remove a specific white space in a string python

Tags: python, removing-whitespace, split

I am splitting and removing white spaces like this.

```
team =  "Hisingsbacka - Guldhedens IK"
homeTeam, awayTeam = team.replace(' ','').split("-")
```

If i were to print them out it would show:

```
homeTeam = "Hisingsbacka"  <-- This one is ok for this case
awayteam = "GuldhedensIK"  <-- not this one, space between the words needed as shown below
```

But I want it too look like this:

```
homeTeam = "Hisingsbacka" 
awayteam = "Guldhedens IK"
```

Please do note i have several stings that are getting parsed from the web and some of them have the same "style/format" or whatever you would call it as **awayTeam** meaning " word1 word2 " So sometimes both sides will have that format, sometimes only the right side, sometimes only the left side.

Comment: you can replace `' - '` with `'-'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just split for " - "

```
team =  "Hisingsbacka - Guldhedens IK"
homeTeam, awayTeam = team.split(" - " )
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't remove whitespace then; use `str.strip()` on the results *after* splitting:

```
team =  "Hisingsbacka - Guldhedens IK"
homeTeam, awayTeam = (t.strip() for t in team.split("-"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In terms of efficiency the answer below should be faster right? No for looped is being used there? @Martijn Pieters

Comment: I'd not worry about efficiency unless you are doing this in a time-critical loop. My method should be used if the amount of whitespace can vary; it'll work equally well on `' foo bar -baz'` as `'spam-ham'`. If you are certain that you always have the space-dash-space separator, split on this three characters and don't strip.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a regular expression might be a good way to go:

```
>>> import re
>>> SPLIT_RE = re.compile(r'\s*-\s*')
>>> SPLIT_RE.split('foo - bar')
['foo', 'bar']
>>> SPLIT_RE.split('foo -     bar')
['foo', 'bar']
>>> SPLIT_RE.split('foo-     bar')
['foo', 'bar']
```

this splits on any amount of whitespace followed by a `-` and then any amount of whitespace.